# DataTable columns don't line up with Scroll Bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I recently switched my DataTables plugin to use scroll bars instead of pagination. I realized that once I switched it, two strange issues happened. A second row appeared below the column headers with just the sorting arrows and the column headers no longer lined up with the columns. On the first tab its just a little bit off but on subsequent tabs it is really off.

The only way to fix it is by sorting one of the columns after its loaded, where this fixes the issue with the alignment.

I am looking for some assistance in finding where the issue is in my code that is causing this to happen.

[image]

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
    } );

    $('table.table').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
            "scrollY":        "500px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":         false,
            "bInfo" : false
    });

    $('#dt-players-all2').DataTable().search( '' ).draw();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')

    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <!-- Panel Header -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Players Overview
                    </div>
                    <!-- /Panel Header -->

                    <!-- Panel Body -->
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">

                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab-all" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-qb" data-toggle="tab">QB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-rb" data-toggle="tab">RB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-wr" data-toggle="tab">WR</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-te" data-toggle="tab">TE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-flex" data-toggle="tab">FLEX</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab-dst" data-toggle="tab">DST</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-all">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dt-players-all">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Position</th>
                                                <th>Player</th>
                                                <th>Team</th>
                                                <th>Opponent</th>
                                                <th>Game</th>
                                                <th>Opp. Rank</th>
                                                <th>FPPG</th>
                                                <th>Salary</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                            @foreach ($players as $player)

                                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                    <td>{{$player->position}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->team}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->opponent}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->status}}</td>
                                                    <td class="center">0</td>
                                                    <td class="center">{{$player->fppg}}</td>
                                                    <td class="center">${{$player->salary}}</td>
                                                </tr>

                                            @endforeach

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-qb">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dt-players-all2">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Position</th>
                                                <th>Player</th>
                                                <th>Team</th>
                                                <th>Opponent</th>
                                                <th>Game</th>
                                                <th>Opp. Rank</th>
                                                <th>FPPG</th>
                                                <th>Salary</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                                            @foreach ($players as $player)

                                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                    <td>{{$player->position}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->team}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->opponent}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$player->status}}</td>
                                                    <td class="center">0</td>
                                                    <td class="center">{{$player->fppg}}</td>
                                                    <td class="center">${{$player->salary}}</td>
                                                </tr>

                                            @endforeach

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /Panel Body -->

                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Your code works fine, just make sure you're using the latest DataTables version.

Also if you're using Responsive extension you need to use  [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) API method to recalculate the widths used by Scroller extension after a change in the display.

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $.each($.fn.dataTable.tables(true), function(){
      $(this).DataTable()
         .columns.adjust()
         .responsive.recalc();
   });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swjev1pL/3/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I actually found this on their forums from the developer $( $.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable().columns.adjust(); where it fixed the issue when I visit different tabs. The problem is still persistent on the first tab though because its inside of the tab toggle. Do you know how I can fix that? I tried moving it out to the document.ready section but no luck.

Comment: @BrettPowell,  `$.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable().columns.adjust();` works for DataTables 1.10.7 and earlier, the code I posted works for DataTables 1.10.8 and above. I have updated my demo to show that it works for tables on all tabs.

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason that doesn't work for me. I pasted it exactly as you have it and its still broken as shown as my screenshot above. Only when I use the line from my previous comment does it work right when I click tabs, just the first tab loaded isn't correct.

Comment: @BrettPowell, this is your exact code http://jsfiddle.net/swjev1pL/3/ and it works fine. Use [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) to get JS/CSS files and make sure you're including Responsive extension.